# Removing the extension name with terminal command find

Tags: shell

I am writing a shell command to find files that end with .sh but display the name without the extension, for example :

```
file1.sh -> file1

file2_sh.sh -> file2_sh
```

I wrote the following :

```
find . -name '*.sh' | tr '.sh' ' '
```

The outcome or the first example is :

```
file1.sh -> file1

file2_sh.sh -> file2_
#here it should keep '_sh' but removes all ocurrences of sh
```

What should I do to keep the '_sh' and only remove the last occurence after the dot.

Thank you very much

Comment: Oh no , that was a typo, fixed it. I just really wanted to remove the '.sh' . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr '.sh' ' '` will replace every instance of `s`, `h`, or `.` with a space.  It does not care about grouping.  You want something like:

```
find . -name '*.sh' | sed 's/\.sh$//'
```

Comment: I tried sed but couldn't get the right combination. Guess I was missing the $ sign. thanks!